# How to change position of top navigation bar in sharepoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer

I am working on branding a SharePoint site which requires styling the top navigation bar and placing it below the site icon. I moved the classes within `seattle.html` page to implement this but this led to added errors.

**Error 1 :** 
The top navigation bar is now also displayed in the upload window when I try to upload a document.

**Error 2 :** The drop down options in top nav bar show some dots on the left.
How do I resolve this?

Comment: is below answer helps you to solve your errors?

Answer (score 2):

**For Error 1:** 
Add below CSS class to your top nav in `seatle.html`

```
 class="ms-dialogHidden"
```

**For Error 2:**

Inspect the element in any browser to identify the CSS & add below CSS in that class

```
list-style:none;
```